# python re.sub - alternative replacement patterns

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, backreference, capture-group

I want to provide alternative replacement patterns to re.sub.

Let's say i've got two search patterns as alternatives, like this:

```
re.sub(r"[A-Z]+|[a-z]+", replacementpattern, string)
```

and instead of providing one replacement pattern I would like to somehow catch which search pattern alternative was matched and provide alternative replacement patterns.
Is this possible?
Thanks.

PS. code specifics here are irrelevant, it's a general question.

Comment: Yes it is. Read the regexp documentation. You're looking for capturing parenthesizes.

Comment: I'm aware of the grouping options in search patterns and then using \number reference inside replacement pattern. What i want to do is: if group \1 was matched then replace string with 'a', if group \2 then replace with 'b'.

Comment: Tagged [tag:capture-group] [tag:backreference], since that's what your question is about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to `re.sub()`. In the function you can return the value needed based on the captured group. A simple code for illustration:

```
>>> def fun(m):
...   if m:
...     if m.group(1):
...        return 'x'
...     else:
...        return 'y'


>>>print re.sub(r"([A-Z]+)|([a-z]+)", fun , "ab")
```

The function `fun()` checks if the match succeeded and based on the captured group, returns the replacement string. If `[A-Z]+` was matched, `x` is the replacement string else `[a-z]+` was matched and `y` is the replacement string.

For more information : [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you would just use two replacements:

```
re.sub(r"[A-Z]+", replacement1, string)
re.sub(r"[a-z]+", replacement2, string)
```

Anticlimactic, right?

It's actually less code than the alternatives usually, and it's far clearer what you're doing.